# Adding a data-* attribute to charts with r2d3.js

Tags: internet-explorer-8, d3.js

I am trying to add data-link attributes within charts created with d3.js, the issue I'm having is once the charts go through r2d3.js for ie8 support the data-link attribute "gets lost" somehow, I'm not sure what happens. Here is my code:

```
var path = group.selectAll("path")
                .data(pie(tempObj))
               .enter().append("path")
                .attr("data-link", function () { return obj.Name.Target; })
                .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i) })
                .attr("d", arc)

                .on('click', function (d) {
                    alert('click');
                });
```

Comment: have you tried logging `obj.Name.Target` to make sure it is returning something?

Comment: After spending some time banging my head on the table, and doing some research, I found that in the VML elements are quite limiting in what you can do with them. I will close this question bcs. what I was ultimately trying to do, make the VML shape elements interactive, is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate goal of making the VML shape elements, produced by r2d3.js in the process of converting charts for ie8, interactive breaks jQuery and therefore not worth the trouble. If anyone else is reading this I suggest trying another way of making interactive charts with d3.js and r2d3.js. I have used anchor tags and text within charts to accomplish this.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7071

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/rotemb/archive/2011/04/10/asp-net-mvc-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-failed.aspx

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/13